# Ngrok with 302 moved in Prestashop local server

Tags: rest, localhost, prestashop-1.6, ngrok

I have a rest API set up as a module in Prestashop 1.6, and I can access without problem to it and make appropriate calls in my local server (localhost:8888).

On the other hand, when I set up ngrok, I receive a new domain to have my localhost available for API calls from the outside. However, I receive **302-moved response**. Do you know if the problem is on how Prestashop treats these calls according to configuration? Can you help me? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I continued checking and this does not only happen to API calls, but also to the delivery of the main frontpage in localhost:8888. This seems clearly that this is a Prestashop config issue. Some ideas?

Comment: I don't know what you use to execute API calls, but do you have it set to follow redirections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution had to do with the setup of URL_DOMAIN in table ps_configuration, where PS_SHOP_DOMAIN and PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL must be set to the ngrok's setup domain name (xxxxx.ngrok.io). And the same for table ps_shop_url, where fields domain and domain_ssl must be set to ngrok's domain name too (xxxxx.ngrok.io).

Answer (score 2):

Directly modifying it in the database didn't help to me: for some reason Prestashop does not fetch the updated values.

Having it modified through the admin console worked fine though.

It is pretty hidden, you have to go to Traffic & SEO and then scroll down until you find this :

[image: Where to find the configuration.]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you. That's a different approach, but that exactly does the same. Did you commit changes in DDBB when you made the changes directly on the tables?